# How to use hooks in multiple rendered inputs?

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I'm creating the form to my app. Problem i'm facing is whenever i click add and generate another row of inputs i got an "Rendered more hooks than during the previous render" error.

I have a "benefit" input with checkbox. When user checks it i want to render another 2 inputs (in the same row) with KPI. Hook works perfectly fine if there is only one row. When i add another row the error occurs.

```
const renderBenefitFields = (benefit, index, fields) => {
  const [hidden, setHidden] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div key={index}>
      <InputGroup>
        <Input
          name={`${benefit}.projectBenefitData`}
          type="text"
          component={renderField}
          label="Benefit of the project"
        />
        <InputGroupAddon addonType="append">
          <InputGroupText>
            <Input
              addon
              type="checkbox"
              aria-label="Mesurable benefit?"
              onChange={() => setHidden(!hidden)}
            />
          </InputGroupText>
          <InputGroupText>Benefit mesurable </InputGroupText>
        </InputGroupAddon>
        <Trash
          className="align-middle"
          size={25}
          onClick={() => fields.remove(index)}
        />
        Show KPI inputs? {hidden === false ? "false" : "true"}
      </InputGroup>
    </div>
  );
};

const renderBenefits = ({ fields }) => (
  <div>
    {fields.map(renderBenefitFields)}
    <PlusCircle
      className="align-baseline"
      size={24}
      onClick={() => fields.push({})}
    />
  </div>
);
```

Perfect solution would be: when user checks the box react will show another two inputs.

Comment: You're using hooks in a function, not a function component, and React can't properly know the hook boundary, as it were.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As [Ross Hunter](https://stackoverflow.com/users/11737564/ross-hunter) mentioned,
1. You should capitalize your component, i.e. `RenderBenefitFields`
2. No mutation on state/props, in `onClick={() => fields.push({})}`

In addition, you should call your RenderBenefitFields in renderBenefits as following:

```
{fields.map((props, index) => <RenderBenefitFields key={index} {...props} />)}
```

P.S. You can use a unique key instead of index, depending on your situation.

Comment: Almost working good, now i can render many inputs, but they share the same value.

Comment: I am not sure why they share the same value. Some may cause that:  
1. The key is not unique
2. The input value is from uncontrolled to controlled component
Here is an example: 
```
function RenderBenefitFields() {
  const [value, setValue] = useState('')
  return <input value={value} onChange={e => setValue(e.target.value)} />
}

```

Answer (score 0):

1. The name of user-defined components needs to be capitalized.
2. The onClick callback in PlusCircle looks like it's directly mutating state. That's a big problem for React, and almost certainly the root of your issue. I can explain further if you need sometime I'm not on mobile